# current url in a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how do i get the current url of the view i'm on as well as the fqdn of the machine to form a hyperlink that will go in an email?

Comment: What do you mean by the URL of the view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Request.Path %>
```

And you can pre-pend that with your base URL, which should stay consistent throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.Url
```

will give u the whole request url