# How to get the page origin in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, request

I'm looking for the equivalent of this javascript

```
window.location.origin
```

but server side, while building mvc pages.

For example, if you are here
http://website.com/123,
it would return

```
http://website.com
```

Its important that i have the "http://" part

Comment: Turned out that was already asked... possible duplicate of [How to get current page URL in MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm a fan of

```
string url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.length > 1
  ? Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, string.Empty)
  : url;
```

Keeps your Http/Https, Port (if applicable), and HostName/IP.

[DotNetFiddle Examples](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lp74KW)

Updated to Account for PathAndQuery length of 1.

Comment: +1. Obviously this is not how one should manipulate Url (UriBuilder would be safer) but ok for most cases.

Comment: This will not work if `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` is equal to `/` i.e empty.

Comment: @libraheem Good catch!  Updated

Answer (score 1):

you could try

```
@String.Format("{0}://{1}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority)
```

Or

```
@String.Format("{0}://{1}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host)
```

Authority will include the port number

Comment: I think you'll have an extra `:` on your Authority.

Comment: @ErikPhilips It doesn't seem to in my test

Comment: oh yeah you're right, forgot were the port is on url, I use it so rarely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for [Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url) or RawUrl.

[Uri.Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx) of Request.Url will give you info on http/https difference.

Comment: Request.Url will also include `/123`.

Comment: @JohnH, I've updated the answer... Also Manatherin's answer(+1) already includes all.

Comment: Neither of these will give what was requested.  Taking the following URL into consideration `http://localhost:63105/home/index`, Request.Url will return `http://localhost:63105/home/index` and Request.RawUrl will return `/home/index`.  Both of our answers are inferior to Erik's, so I'll remove mine.

Answer (score -1):

The window.location.origin in javascript returns the protocol, port (if any), domain and extension of the current url.

If you want to get the same information from an URL, the accepted answers will provide that to you.

If you want the same behavior, ie a piece of javascript is calling your server method and you want to know where it is calling from, you can inspect the HttpRequest.URLReferrer. However this can be spoofed easily and thus is not reliable.

Comment: Using `UrlReferrer ` is dangerous! It can be [spoofed / set to anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing). That opens a whole big can of worms if you're not escaping correctly etc. (XSS for example). Also, when I hit the page coming from, say, Google.com your method will return google.com, not website.com. Never trust user-input; the referrer is exactly that.

Comment: @RobIII You're correct. Updated my answer to reflect my original opinion.