# How to get URL value in C# MVC and put it in an Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, html.actionlink

So I have this page which will show an individual record from a database.  So my URL will look like:

`mysite.com/Vehicle/Edit/1`

or it may end it 2,3,4,5 etc.. depending on the record its on.  Basically I need a link in this page that will take me to another page but have the same value in the url, so it could look like:

`mysite.com/Owner/Add/1`

Or it could end in 2,3,4,5 etc.. depending on which record the link was in.

How do I do this using C# MVC, im using Razor if that makes any difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use one of the [`Html.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helpers.

Say you're passing in a `Model` to your view that has a property called `Id`.  You could use `Html.ActionLink` like this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Add Owner", "Add", "Owner", new { id = Model.Id }, null)`

The first argument is the text that the link will display.
The second argument is the name of the `Action` to call.
The third argument is the name of the `Controller` the `Action` is in.
The fourth argument is the route values for the `Action`.
The fifth argument is for html attributes.  Say you wanted to add a `class` to your link. Instead of null, you could use `new { @class = "my-link-class" }`.  Notice the `@` in front of class.  That is because `class` is a reserved word.  If you were setting `style`, you would just do this: `new { style = "background-color: #ffffff;" }`.

All of this is assuming your Add `Action` takes in an `int id`.  So something like this:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
{
   // Do stuff.
}
```

Here are the docs for the specific `Html.ActionLink` overload I used in my example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should have actually been something I should have figured out easily.  But thanks, great help

Answer (score 0):

See this post to get the URL. [How to get current page URL in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3)

Once you have the url, you can just pick off the trailing characters after the final '/'