# How do I get the current url in a Razor template served by NancyFX?

Tags: razor, nancy

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5304805/95195) the way to do it in MVC Razor is `@Request.RawUrl`, `@Request.Url.ToString()` or `@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

On my razor page, ReSharper resolves `@Request` to `using @Nancy`, and I can't find an instance of [HttpRequestBase.RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.rawurl.aspx).

How do I get the RawUrl from a Nancy served template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently you would have to either expose it on your `ViewModel` or derive your own page base class form the `NancyRazorViewBase<TModel>` class, and expose it from the `RenderContext.Context.Request.Url` property

You can see an example of creating your own page base class here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.Tests/GreetingViewBase.cs

I just submitted a pull-request with a code change that makes the following possible from your Razor views https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1633

```
@Request.Url
@Context.Request.Url
```

As soon as the pull-request has been accepted you will be able to use it by using our bleeding edge builds https://www.myget.org/gallery/nancyfx

It will then be part of the Nancy v1-alpha release on the official Nuget feed, once we release that

Comment: I'm using Nancy 0.23.2 and I do it with: `@Html.RenderContext.Context.Request.Url`, for example `<a href="~/login?returnUrl=@Html.RenderContext.Context.Request.Url">Login</a>`