# How to get Url from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

is there another way on getting the current url in mvc same in the code in window.location.href,
so that i can manage the content?,

**Problem**

> i have a url https://Mylink.com/Data?#address=ph that i want
>   to get address value. my problem is, when i tried to get the url by doing Request in controller,
>   only the https://Mylink.com/Data will get, querystring is also empty.

My Codes:

```
public string Data()
{
    var url = Request.Url;
    var addr = url.IndexOf('#') > -1 ? url.Substring(url.IndexOf('#'),url.Length): "";
    return addr;
}
```

any suggestion will be accepted, thank again in advance

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3

Comment: You can't get # values in the URL in server side code as the browser simply does not send them to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your querystring *is* empty. The `#` and everything after it is known as the fragment and is a clientside only thing. In general this is not sent to the server.

If you need information from here on the server then chances are it should be in the querystring instead of the fragment.

Comment: And then you can use `Request.Url.Query`

Comment: yup is # is the problem, but is there another way on getting the whole url in controller so that i'll split the # character?

Comment: @A.J: See the question that this has been marked a duplicate of for some ways round it. Essentially it boils down to having script get the fragment and putting it somewhere you can access it. If this is a form post then you could put it in a hidden field. If its a GET request then your only option is to put it in the querystring.

Comment: thank again sir, i'll used window.location to solved this.