# How to get the URL of the posting page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I want to get the url of the page from where ajax post is being done.
I have check all the parameters of multipart form data but not got exactly.

Please provide help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you want it in the server side? did you check the context.request object?

Comment: you could send a parameter in the ajax that tells you what page sent the call.

Comment: Hi @LiranBo yes I have checked all the keys and value context.request.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3)

Comment: Hi LiranBo

Thanks for suggestion but Request.RawUrl and Request.Url.OriginalString  give the url of current page i.e receiver page. But I need the URL of posting page not receiver page.

Comment: I see, I would go with @devlin carnate suggestion then. you need the previous page...