# Get URL in HTML / cshtml

Tags: html, url, razor

I want to get the current URL into a string that I can use for e.g. share functionality later.

```
String strPathAndQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
```

I get the error:

> The name `HttpContext` does not exist in the current context.

Is there another way?

Comment: Where are you using the above statement? In View?

Comment: Yes in mypage.cshtml

Answer (score 11):

In case you are using MVC 3 or higher: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3) is a related questions.

In case you are using ASP .Net MVC Core 1.0 you should use this code:

```
Context.Request.Path
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do `Request.RawUrl` and it should return the entire current page URL.

So you would do:

```
@{
  string strPathAndQuery = Request.RawUrl;    
}
```

Comment: I get the same error msg. I believe it is something wrong with the dependencies, since I need to use system.web.mvc..But when I try to add that NuGet I get errors in my References.

Comment: What kind of errors? What does your view look like?

Comment: You can also look at this question to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser?rq=1

Comment: I'll get back too you with the errors. I tired the string url = window.location.href; but getting the same The name 'window' does not exist in the current context.